# ASPX authentication cookie issue in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, cookies, virtual-directory

I have 3 applications running at my end.

1. RootSite
2. RootSite/VirtualDirectory1
3. RootSite/VirtualDirectory2

I have a login page in three of these applications. When I login in either of these applications the .ASPXAUTH cookie is set but I am seeing that all of the three applications are updating the same .ASPXAUTH cookie instead of creating individual one. For example a user login on "RootSite", .ASPXAUTH cookie is created, now the user comes and login in the application "RootSite/VirtualDirectory1" and this time I am seeing the same .ASPXAUTH cookie is updating. I am confirming this because the created date of this cookie has been changed. So this means instead of creating a new cookie it is using the same cookie. How can I resolve this ? I don't want to interfere the logged-in logged-out status of one application with the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add\Change the name attribute in your Forms Authentication web config entry - See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22HTTP%3a%2f%2fSCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM%2f.NETCONFIGURATION%2fV2.0%23%40NAME%22%29;k%28%22HTTP%3a%2f%2fSCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM%2f.NETCONFIGURATION%2fV2.0%23CONFIGURATION%2fSYSTEM.WEB%2fAUTHENTICATION%2fFORMS%22%29;k%28%22HTTP%3a%2f%2fSCHEMAS.MICROSOFT.COM%2f.NETCONFIGURATION%2fV2.0%23FORMS%22%29;k%28VS.XMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true)

Comment: I would have n number of virtual directories. I don't think changing the name of cookie for each site would be a good approach.

Comment: Can you atleast attempt this approach, to help determine if it's an issue with the forms auth cookie?  If it is, you can programmatically alter the name of the cookie...